# Understanding treeReduce() in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, reduce

You can see the implementation here:
https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ffa05c84fe75663fc33f3d954d1cb1e084ab3280/python/pyspark/rdd.py#L804

How does it different from the 'normal' `reduce` function?

What does it mean `depth = 2`?

I don't want that the reducer function will pass linearly on the partitions,
but reduce each available pairs first, and then will iterate like that until i have only one pair and reduce it to 1, as shown in the picture:

[image]

Does `treeReduce` achieve that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Standard `reduce` is taking a wrapped version of the function and using it to [`mapPartitions`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ffa05c84fe75663fc33f3d954d1cb1e084ab3280/python/pyspark/rdd.py#L799). After that results are collected and [reduced locally](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ffa05c84fe75663fc33f3d954d1cb1e084ab3280/python/pyspark/rdd.py#L801) on a driver. If number of the partitions is large and/or function you use is expensive it places a significant load on a single machine.

The first phase of the `treeReduce` is pretty much the same as above but after that partial results are merged in parallel and only the final aggregation is performed on the driver.

`depth` is [*suggested depth of the tree*](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=treereduce#pyspark.RDD.treeReduce) and since depth of the node in tree is defined as number of edges between the root and the node it should you give you more or less an expected pattern although it looks like a distributed aggregation [can be stopped early](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ffa05c84fe75663fc33f3d954d1cb1e084ab3280/python/pyspark/rdd.py#L941) in some cases.

It is worth to note that what you get with `treeReduce` is not a binary tree. Number of the partitions is adjusted on each level and most likely more than a two partitions will be merged at once.

Compared to the standard reduce, tree based version [performs `reduceByKey` with each iteration](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/ffa05c84fe75663fc33f3d954d1cb1e084ab3280/python/pyspark/rdd.py#L953) and it means a lot of data shuffling. If number of the partitions is relatively small it will be much cheaper to use plain `reduce`. If you suspect that the final phase of the `reduce` is a bottleneck `tree*` version could be worth trying.

Comment: How can i implement something like in my picture?

Comment: If your picture represents partitions then as far as I can tell `tree*` methods are the right choice.

Comment: yes,each block is a partition. should I pick depth = 2?
Because the overall depth is log(num_partitions)

Comment: Also, why not always use treeReduce instead of reduce?

Comment: Because it is much more expensive. Regarding `depth` parameter 2 should do the trick although keep in mind that it is not a binary tree. I've edited the answer to provide more details

Comment: But how can i get this binary tree? how can I implement this, maybe treeReduce() isn't the best option?

Comment: It simply doesn't make sense to use binary tree. Why would you want something like this?

Comment: because in my algorithm, it will be the correct way. If i reduced a partition, i dont want to reduce it again and again. I want to do that at least as possible. The binary tree will achieve that!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88239/discussion-between-zero323-and-member555).

Comment: @zero323 Where do you learn all these stuff? Are you contributor to Apache Spark Project?

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto Not really. I've made some PR but nothing serious. Some reading, some coding and a lot of SO ;) BTW Care to vote http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310265/1560062

Comment: @zero323 How to determine whether the number of partitions is to large?

Comment: @G_cy Monitoring, tunning and common sense. Adding 1000s of integers on a single machine won't be problem, very-expensive-operation-on-very-large-object can throttle the driver even if with dozens of collected tasks.