# treeReduce vs reduceByKey in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I saw the following post a little bit back: [Understanding TreeReduce in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32281417/understadning-treereduce-in-spark)

I am still trying to exactly understand when to use a treeReduce vs a reduceByKey. I think we can use a universal example like a word count to help me further understand what is going on.

- Does it always make sense to use reduceByKey in a word count?
- Or is there a particular size of data when treeReduce makes more sense?
- Are there particular cases or rules of thumbs when treeReduce is the better option?
- Also this may be answered in the above based on reduceByKey but does anything change with reduceByKeyLocally and treeReduce
- How do I appropriately determine depth?

**Edit**: So playing in spark-shell, I think I fundamentally don't understand the concept of treeReduce but hopefully an example and those question help.

```
res2: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((D,1), (18964,1), (D,1), (1,1), ("",1), ("",1), ("",1), ("",1), ("",1), (1,1))

scala> val reduce = input.reduceByKey(_+_)
reduce: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ShuffledRDD[11] at reduceByKey at <console>:25

scala> val tree = input.treeReduce(_+_, 2)
<console>:25: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (String, Int)
 required: String
       val tree = input.treeReduce(_+_, 2)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a fundamental difference between the two-`reduceByKey` is only available on key-value pair RDDs, while `treeReduce`  is a generalization of `reduce` operation on any RDD. `reduceByKey` is used for implementing `treeReduce` but they are not related in any other sense.

`reduceByKey` performs reduction per each key, resulting in an RDD; it is not an "action" in RDD sense but a transformation that returns a ShuffleRDD. This is equivalent to `groupByKey` followed by a `map` that does key-wise reduction (check [this](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html) why using `groupByKey` is inefficient).

On the other hand, `treeAggregate` is a generalization of `reduce` function, inspired from `AllReduce`. This is an "action" in spark sense, returning the result on the master node. As explained the link posted in your question, after performing local reduce operation, `reduce` performs rest of the computation on the master, which can be very burdensome (especially in machine learning when the reduce function results in a large vectors or a matrices). Instead, `treeReduce` perform the reduction in parallel using `reduceByKey` (this is done by creating a key-value pair RDD on the fly, with the keys determined by the depth of the tree; check implementation [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/128c29035b4e7383cc3a9a6c7a9ab6136205ac6c/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L1129)).

So, to answer your first two questions, you have to use `reduceByKey` for word count since you are interested in getting per word-count and `treeReduce` is not appropriate here. The other two questions are not related to this topic.