# Efficient string suffix detection

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, string-matching

I am working with PySpark on a huge dataset, where I want to filter the data frame based on strings in another data frame. For example,

```
dd = spark.createDataFrame(["something.google.com","something.google.com.somethingelse.ac.uk","something.good.com.cy", "something.good.com.cy.mal.org"], StringType()).toDF('domains')
+----------------------------------------+
|domains                                 |
+----------------------------------------+
|something.google.com                    |
|something.google.com.somethingelse.ac.uk|
|something.good.com.cy                   |
|something.good.com.cy.mal.org           |
+----------------------------------------+  

dd1 =  spark.createDataFrame(["google.com", "good.com.cy"], StringType()).toDF('gooddomains')
+-----------+
|gooddomains|
+-----------+
|google.com |
|good.com.cy|
+-----------+
```

I assume that `domains` and `gooddomains` are valid domain names.

What I want to do is filter out the matching strings in `dd` that do not end with `dd1`. So in the above example, I want to filter out row 1 and row 3, to end up with

```
+----------------------------------------+
|domains                                 |
+----------------------------------------+
|something.google.com.somethingelse.ac.uk|
|something.good.com.cy.mal.org           |
+----------------------------------------+
```

My current solution (as shown below) can only account for domains up to 3 'words'. If I were to add say, `verygood.co.ac.uk` in `dd1` (i.e. whitelist), then It will fail.

```
def split_filter(x, whitelist):
    splitted1 = x.select(F.split(x['domains'], '\.').alias('splitted_domains'))
    last_two = splitted1.select(F.concat(splitted1.splitted_domains[F.size(splitted1.splitted_domains)-2], \
       F.lit('.'), \
       splitted1.splitted_domains[F.size(splitted1.splitted_domains)-1]).alias('last_two'))
    last_three = splitted1.select(F.concat(splitted1.splitted_domains[F.size(splitted1.splitted_domains)-3], \
       F.lit('.'), \
       splitted1.splitted_domains[F.size(splitted1.splitted_domains)-2], \
       F.lit('.'), \
       splitted1.splitted_domains[F.size(splitted1.splitted_domains)-1]).alias('last_three'))
    x = x.withColumn('id', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
    last_two = last_two.withColumn('id', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
    last_three = last_three.withColumn('id', F.monotonically_increasing_id())
    final_d = x.join(last_two, ['id']).join(last_three, ['id'])
    df1 = final_d.join(whitelist, final_d['last_two'] == whitelist['domains'], how = 'left_anti')
    df2 = df1.join(whitelist, df1['last_three'] == whitelist['domains'], how = 'left_anti')
    return df2.drop('id')
```

I am using Spark 2.3.0 with Python 2.7.5.

Comment: Have you looked at [Efficient String Matching in Apache Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938672/efficient-string-matching-in-apache-spark)? You could also try using regex instead of a `udf`.

Comment: Yes I have looked at that link. I don't want the distance. I just need to filter out.

Comment: @Sotos if you have time try to edit  your question and be a little more specific in section here "What I want to do is filter out the matching strings in dd that do not end with dd1"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's extend the `domains` for slightly better coverage:

```
domains = spark.createDataFrame([
    "something.google.com",  # OK
    "something.google.com.somethingelse.ac.uk", # NOT OK 
    "something.good.com.cy", # OK 
    "something.good.com.cy.mal.org",  # NOT OK
    "something.bad.com.cy",  # NOT OK
    "omgalsogood.com.cy", # NOT OK
    "good.com.cy",   # OK 
    "sogood.example.com",  # OK Match for shorter redundant, mismatch on longer
    "notsoreal.googleecom" # NOT OK
], "string").toDF('domains')

good_domains =  spark.createDataFrame([
    "google.com", "good.com.cy", "alsogood.com.cy",
    "good.example.com", "example.com"  # Redundant case
], "string").toDF('gooddomains')
```

Now... **A naive solution, using only Spark SQL primitives**, is to simplify your current approach a bit. Since you've stated that it is safe to assume that these are valid public domains, we can define a function like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, regexp_extract

def suffix(c): 
    return regexp_extract(c, "([^.]+\\.[^.]+$)", 1)
```

which extract top level domain and first level subdomain:

```
domains_with_suffix = (domains
    .withColumn("suffix", suffix("domains"))
    .alias("domains"))
good_domains_with_suffix = (good_domains
    .withColumn("suffix", suffix("gooddomains"))
    .alias("good_domains"))

domains_with_suffix.show()
```

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|             domains|              suffix|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|something.google.com|          google.com|
|something.google....|               ac.uk|
|something.good.co...|              com.cy|
|something.good.co...|             mal.org|
|something.bad.com.cy|              com.cy|
|  omgalsogood.com.cy|              com.cy|
|         good.com.cy|              com.cy|
|  sogood.example.com|         example.com|
|notsoreal.googleecom|notsoreal.googleecom|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Now we can outer join:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import (
    col, concat, lit, monotonically_increasing_id, sum as sum_
)

candidates = (domains_with_suffix
    .join(
        good_domains_with_suffix,
        col("domains.suffix") == col("good_domains.suffix"), 
        "left"))
```

and filter the result:

```
is_good_expr = (
    col("good_domains.suffix").isNotNull() &      # Match on suffix
    (

        # Exact match
        (col("domains") == col("gooddomains")) |
        # Subdomain match
        col("domains").endswith(concat(lit("."), col("gooddomains")))
    )
)

not_good_domains = (candidates
    .groupBy("domains")  # .groupBy("suffix", "domains") - see the discussion
    .agg((sum_(is_good_expr.cast("integer")) > 0).alias("any_good"))
    .filter(~col("any_good"))
    .drop("any_good"))

not_good_domains.show(truncate=False)
```

```
+----------------------------------------+
|domains                                 |
+----------------------------------------+
|omgalsogood.com.cy                      |
|notsoreal.googleecom                    |
|something.good.com.cy.mal.org           |
|something.google.com.somethingelse.ac.uk|
|something.bad.com.cy                    |
+----------------------------------------+
```

This is better than a [Cartesian product required for direct join with `LIKE`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33168970/10938362), but is unsatisfactory to brute-force and in the worst case scenario requires two shuffles - one for `join` (this can be skipped if `good_domains` are small enough to `broadcasted`), and the another one for `group_by` + `agg`.

Unfortunately Spark SQL doesn't allow custom partitioner to use only one shuffle for both (it is however possible with [composite key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38918342/10938362) in RDD API) and optimizer is not smart enough yet, to optimize `join(_, "key1")` and `.groupBy("key1", _)`.

If you can accept some false negatives you can **go probabilistic**. First let's build probabilistic counter (here using [`bounter`](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/bounter) with small help from [`toolz`](https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz/))

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import concat_ws, reverse, split
from bounter import bounter
from toolz.curried import identity, partition_all

# This is only for testing on toy examples, in practice use more realistic value
size_mb = 20      
chunk_size = 100

def reverse_domain(c):
    return concat_ws(".", reverse(split(c, "\\.")))

def merge(acc, xs):
    acc.update(xs)
    return acc

counter = sc.broadcast((good_domains
    .select(reverse_domain("gooddomains"))
    .rdd.flatMap(identity)
    # Chunk data into groups so we reduce the number of update calls
    .mapPartitions(partition_all(chunk_size))
    # Use tree aggregate to reduce pressure on the driver, 
    # when number of partitions is large*
    # You can use depth parameter for further tuning
    .treeAggregate(bounter(need_iteration=False, size_mb=size_mb), merge, merge)))
```

next define an user defined function function like this

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from toolz import accumulate

def is_good_counter(counter):
    def is_good_(x):
        return any(
            x in counter.value 
            for x in accumulate(lambda x, y: "{}.{}".format(x, y), x.split("."))
        )

    @pandas_udf("boolean", PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
    def _(xs):
        return xs.apply(is_good_)
    return _
```

and filter the `domains`:

```
domains.filter(
    ~is_good_counter(counter)(reverse_domain("domains"))
).show(truncate=False)
```

```
+----------------------------------------+
|domains                                 |
+----------------------------------------+
|something.google.com.somethingelse.ac.uk|
|something.good.com.cy.mal.org           |
|something.bad.com.cy                    |
|omgalsogood.com.cy                      |
|notsoreal.googleecom                    |
+----------------------------------------+
```

*In Scala* this could be done with `bloomFilter`

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.util.sketch.BloomFilter

def reverseDomain(c: Column) = concat_ws(".", reverse(split(c, "\\.")))

val checker = good_domains.stat.bloomFilter(
  // Adjust values depending on the data
  reverseDomain($"gooddomains"), 1000, 0.001 
)

def isGood(checker: BloomFilter) = udf((s: String) => 
  s.split('.').toStream.scanLeft("") {
    case ("", x) => x
    case (acc, x) => s"${acc}.${x}"
}.tail.exists(checker mightContain _))


domains.filter(!isGood(checker)(reverseDomain($"domains"))).show(false)
```

```
+----------------------------------------+
|domains                                 |
+----------------------------------------+
|something.google.com.somethingelse.ac.uk|
|something.good.com.cy.mal.org           |
|something.bad.com.cy                    |
|omgalsogood.com.cy                      |
|notsoreal.googleecom                    |
+----------------------------------------+
```

and if needed, [shouldn't be hard to call such code from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36023860/how-to-use-a-scala-class-inside-pyspark).

This might be still not fully satisfying, due to approximate nature. If you require an exact result you can try to **leverage redundant nature of the data**, for example with [trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/trie) (here using [`datrie`](https://github.com/pytries/datrie) implementation).

If `good_domains` are relatively small you can create a single model, in a similar way as in the probabilistic variant:

```
import string
import datrie


def seq_op(acc, x):
    acc[x] = True
    return acc

def comb_op(acc1, acc2):
    acc1.update(acc2)
    return acc1

trie = sc.broadcast((good_domains
    .select(reverse_domain("gooddomains"))
    .rdd.flatMap(identity)
    # string.printable is a bit excessive if you need standard domain
    # and not enough if you allow internationalized domain names.
    # In the latter case you'll have to adjust the `alphabet`
    # or use different implementation of trie.
    .treeAggregate(datrie.Trie(string.printable), seq_op, comb_op)))
```

define user defined function:

```
def is_good_trie(trie):
    def is_good_(x):
        if not x:
            return False
        else:
            return any(
                x == match or x[len(match)] == "."
                for match in trie.value.iter_prefixes(x)
            )

    @pandas_udf("boolean", PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
    def _(xs):
        return xs.apply(is_good_)

    return _
```

and apply it to the data:

```
domains.filter(
    ~is_good_trie(trie)(reverse_domain("domains"))
).show(truncate=False)
```

```
+----------------------------------------+
|domains                                 |
+----------------------------------------+
|something.google.com.somethingelse.ac.uk|
|something.good.com.cy.mal.org           |
|something.bad.com.cy                    |
|omgalsogood.com.cy                      |
|notsoreal.googleecom                    |
+----------------------------------------+
```

This specific approach works under assumption that all `good_domains` can be compressed into a single trie, but can be easily extended to handle cases where this assumption is not satisfied. For example you can build a single trie per top level domain or suffix (as defined in the naive solution)

```
(good_domains
    .select(suffix("gooddomains"), reverse_domain("gooddomains"))
    .rdd
    .aggregateByKey(datrie.Trie(string.printable), seq_op, comb_op))
```

and then, either load models on demand from serialized version, or use `RDD` operations.

The two non-native methods can be further adjusted depending on the data, business requirements (like false negative tolerance in case of approximate solution) and available resources (driver memory, executor memory, cardinality of `suffixes`, access to distributed POSIX-compliant distributed file system, and so on). There also some trade-offs to consider when choosing between applying these on `DataFrames` and `RDDs` (memory usage, communication and serialization overhead).

---

* See [Understanding treeReduce() in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32281417/10938362)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked and It improved efficiency. Thank you for all the info as well.

Comment: This is really great. +1

Answer (score 4):

If I understand correctly, you just want a left anti join using a simple SQL string matching pattern.

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

dd.alias("l")\
    .join(
        dd1.alias("r"), 
        on=expr("l.domains LIKE concat('%', r.gooddomains)"), 
        how="leftanti"
    )\
    .select("l.*")\
    .show(truncate=False)
#+----------------------------------------+
#|domains                                 |
#+----------------------------------------+
#|something.google.com.somethingelse.ac.uk|
#|something.good.com.cy.mal.org           |
#+----------------------------------------+
```

The expression `concat('%', r.gooddomains)` prepends a wildcard to `r.gooddomains`.

Next, we use `l.domains LIKE concat('%', r.gooddomains)` to find the rows which match this pattern.

Finally, specify `how="leftanti"` in order to keep only the rows that don't match.

---

**Update**: As pointed out in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54481681/efficient-string-suffix-detection/54519135?noredirect=1#comment95885297_54519135) by [@user10938362](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10938362/user10938362) there are 2 flaws with this approach:

1) Since this only looks at matching suffixes, there are edge cases where this produces the wrong results. For example:

> `example.com` should match `example.com` and `subdomain.example.com`, but not `fakeexample.com`

There are two ways to approach this. The first is to modify the `LIKE` expression to handle this. Since we know these are all valid domains, we can check for an exact match or a dot followed by the domain:

```python
like_expr = " OR ".join(
    [
        "(l.domains = r.gooddomains)",
        "(l.domains LIKE concat('%.', r.gooddomains))"
    ]
)

dd.alias("l")\
    .join(
        dd1.alias("r"), 
        on=expr(like_expr), 
        how="leftanti"
    )\
    .select("l.*")\
    .show(truncate=False)
```

Similarly, one can use `RLIKE` with a regular expression pattern with a look-behind.

2) The larger issue is that, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33190103/5858851), joining on a `LIKE` expression will cause a Cartesian Product. If `dd1` is small enough to be broadcast, then this isn't an issue.

Otherwise, you may run into performance issues and will have to try a different approach.

---

More on the PySparkSQL [`LIKE`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#like) operator from the [Apache HIVE docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial):

`A LIKE B`:

> TRUE if string A matches the SQL simple regular expression B, otherwise FALSE. The comparison is done character by character. The `_` character in B matches any character in A (similar to `.` in posix regular expressions), and the `%` character in B matches an arbitrary number of characters in A (similar to `.*` in posix regular expressions). For example, `'foobar' LIKE 'foo'` evaluates to FALSE where as `'foobar' LIKE 'foo___'` evaluates to TRUE and so does `'foobar' LIKE 'foo%'`. To escape `%` use `\` (`%` matches one `%` character). If the data contains a semicolon, and you want to search for it, it needs to be escaped, `columnValue LIKE 'a\;b'`

---

**Note**: This exploits the "trick" of using [`pyspark.sql.functions.expr`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.expr) to [pass in a column value as a parameter to a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140470/using-a-column-value-as-a-parameter-to-a-spark-dataframe-function).